# combine two group by and count conditions into one

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count

In my table, variables are in the following structure: within each `ID`, there are multiple rows of `date` variable, within each date, there are multiple rows of `session` variable, within each session, there are rows of `transactions`. I want to query a table by 2 `group by` conditions: 1) I want to clean the table group by IDs who have under 300 rows of transactions, 2) group by IDs, date, session counts which are larger than 5.

The codes query the data sequentially by two separate blocks, how can I combine them into one?

```
# group by ID
CREATE TABLE A as(
SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2 
    FROM data
    WHERE ID IN
        (SELECT ID
         FROM data 
         GROUP BY ID
         HAVING count(*) < 300)
);

# group by ID, session, transaction
CREATE TABLE B as (
SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2 
    FROM A
    WHERE ID IN
        (SELECT ID
         FROM data 
         GROUP BY ID, date, session
         HAVING count(*) > 5));
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL, please? 8 supports CTE while with 5.7 you'd do it wit subqueries.

Comment: Apologize, I'm actually using psql, I have edited the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to do one query and select against it. It's like making a temp table for just one query.

```
with data_with_many_sessions (
  SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY ID, date, session
  HAVING count(*) > 5
)
SELECT *
FROM data_with_many_sessions 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(*) < 300
```

The same as a subquery would look like...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY ID, date, session
  HAVING count(*) > 5
) as data_with_many_sessions
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(*) < 300
```

Alternatively, you can use [`intersect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) which will return only rows which appear in both queries.

```
SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2
FROM data 
GROUP BY ID, date, session
HAVING count(*) > 5

INTERSECT

SELECT ID, date, session, transaction, v1, v2
FROM data 
GROUP BY ID
HAVING count(*) < 300
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to query a table by 2 group by conditions: 1) I want to clean the table group by IDs who have under 300 rows of transactions, 2) group by IDs, date, session counts which are larger than 5.

I assume you want to combine these two conditions.  You can use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt_transaction,
             count(*) over (partition by id, date_session) as cnt_id_date_session
      from data d
     ) d
where cnt_transaction < 300 and cnt_id_date_session > 5;
```